# Turning a transformer into an inductor

Tags: power-electronics, electromagnetism

If i wind a primary on an inductor can it be used as a step up transformer(assuming the number of turns in the primary are lesser than the secondary).

Comment: Sure thing. Just make sure you don't saturate it. Vt=NAB or Urms=4.44fNAB, take your pick.

Comment: The title and the actual question describe opposite situations. Do you want to use a transformer as a simple inductor (title) or do you want to turn a simple inductur into a transformar (question)?

Comment: Also: **what type** of inductor/transformer, **what frequency** and **what power** are you talking about?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, but it may not work very well because core saturation might be a problem and leakage flux may not give you a voltage ratio that matches the turns ratio